# nginx behind apache ssl configuration

Tags: nginx, ssl, virtualhost, https, apache2

I have an apache webserver who is hosting a website with ssl certificate in front of an nginx server which is also hosting a website (nodejs) but without ssl. I want to configure the domain hosted on nginx to also have ssl but I can't figure it out. The nginx server is configured like this:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;  
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

And apache2.conf like this:

```
<VirtualHost MYIPADDRESS:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com
        ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/example.com.error.log
        ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8080/
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
        ServerAdmin webmaster@site.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried numerous things but always ended up breaking the apache hosted domain, I hope someone can help .

Comment: Why do you have Apache? You could just get rid of it.

Comment: please post output of `# apache2ctl configtest`

Comment: Is Nginx hosting one website or two? This is confusing. I see no point having two web servers.

Comment: SSL should be on port 443, not 80

Comment: @MichaelHampton The Apache server has a very specific configuration and I don't want the hassle of configuring it on nginx.

Comment: @Tim One website is hosted on Apache and an other one on nginx.

Comment: @AlexeyTen if I configure the apache virtualhost to 443 it kills my other domain.

Comment: Choose one web server. I suggest Nginx but Apache is fine too.

Comment: You've spent far more time trying to "fix" this than the few minutes it would take to just get rid of Apache and reconfigure this in nginx.

Comment: @MichaelHampton You're probably right, I'm gonna try moving to nginx. thx

Comment: @MichaelHampton his original question was how to enable SSL in nginx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving apache to nginx did the job.

Comment: Removing the proxypass entries for nginx and a single `ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/` would have helped you either way, but some people are just obssesed with telling others to get rid of Apache instead of configuring it correctly with one simple directive.

Comment: Btw your original configuration for Apache was very good, you just needed to clear one step to make it simpler.